# Не инсталируется discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cтолкнулся с проблемой, при попытке инсталлировать discord.py через pip выдает ошибку,при том что перед этим при попытке инсталляции просто попросило обновить pip (upgrade pip) а после апгрейда постоянно выдает эту ошибку, не понимаю почему

Answer (score 0):

В вашей версии Python - 3.5 - не поддерживаются f-strings. Данная версия языка сейчас является устаревшей, чтобы нормально использовать `discord.py`, обновите Python до версии не ниже 3.8